# Why it displays my code as text using ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, xampp

So I'm using XAMPP in order to display my ASP.NET (.aspx) website on the internet. But when I'm entering the website it just show me all of the HTML as text and not as a functional website.

Any solutions? Thanks.

Comment: Can we see some example code? Likely you are forgetting a tag.

Comment: It doesn't matter which code I'm using, even opening a new web form and adding a <h1>Hello</h1> it shows it as text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you install or change anything in XAMPP that was intended to allow you to use aspx files, as they would be in IIS?  Or are you just using XAMPP as-is out of the box?

XAMPP by default does not display aspx files as they would normally in IIS.

Since they aren't normally recognized, they basically get interpreted as text.

Comment: I didn't add\change anything. But you pretty much display the problem I guess. As someone who recognized the problem, may you please direct me to the right thing to download?

Comment: I've done this guide http://xehroz.tumblr.com/post/43884721903/how-to-run-aspnet-on-xampp but still the same.

Comment: I'm sorry--I've never done it before. I would suggest starting a new question on how to run ASP.NET on Apache.  I would also clarify if you are running it on in windows or Linux.  Could you mark this as the answer, please? Good luck, Naveh